# The key error in dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to use wave-front to find a shortest path. I use a dictionary to record this. I have a error about the key, and I am sure the key is exist. I don't know what happen here.Thank you for your help.[image]

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop
import numpy as np
import traceback
import gui
import common

# The world extents in units.
world_extents = (200, 150)

# The obstacle map.
# Obstacle = 255, free space = 0.
world_obstacles = np.zeros(world_extents, dtype=np.uint8)

# The array of visited cells during search.
visited_nodes = None

# The optimal path between start and goal. This is a list of (x,y) pairs.
optimal_path = []

# Functions for GUI functionality.
def add_obstacle(pos):
    common.set_obstacle(world_obstacles, pos, True)
    common.draw_background(gui, world_obstacles, visited_nodes, optimal_path)
def remove_obstacle(pos):
    common.set_obstacle(world_obstacles, pos, False)
    common.draw_background(gui, world_obstacles, visited_nodes, optimal_path)
def clear_obstacles():
    global world_obstacles
    world_obstacles = np.zeros(world_extents, dtype=np.uint8)
    update_callback()
def update_callback(pos = None):
    # Call path planning algorithm.
    start, goal = gui.get_start_goal()
    if not (start==None or goal==None):
        global optimal_path
        global visited_nodes
        try:
            optimal_path, visited_nodes = dijkstra(start, goal, world_obstacles)
        except Exception, e:
            print traceback.print_exc()
    # Draw new background.
    common.draw_background(gui, world_obstacles, visited_nodes, optimal_path)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Dijkstra algorithm.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allowed movements and costs on the grid.
# Each tuple is: (movement_x, movement_y, cost).
s2 = np.sqrt(2)
movements = [ # Direct neighbors (4N).
              (1,0, 1.), (0,1, 1.), (-1,0, 1.), (0,-1, 1.),
              # Diagonal neighbors.
              # Comment this out to play with 4N only (faster).
              (1,1, s2), (-1,1, s2), (-1,-1, s2), (1,-1, s2),
            ]

def dijkstra(start, goal, obstacles):
    """Dijkstra's algorithm. Fourth version also returns optimal path."""
    # In the beginning, the start is the only element in our front.
    # The first element is the cost of the path from the start to the point.
    # The second element is the position (cell) of the point.
    # The third component is the position we came from when entering the tuple
    #   to the front.
    front = [ (0.001, start, None) ]  # CHANGE 01_d: Add None to this tuple.

    # In the beginning, no cell has been visited.
    extents = obstacles.shape
    visited = np.zeros(extents, dtype=np.float32)

    # Also, we use a dictionary to remember where we came from.
    came_from = {}  # CHANGE 01_d: Add this line to your implementation.
    path=[]
    # While there are elements to investigate in our front.
    while front:
        # Get smallest item and remove from front.
        element=heappop(front)
        # Check if this has been visited already.

        cost, pos, previous = element  # CHANGE 01_d: add 'previous' (as shown).
        #print element
        # Now it is visited. Mark with cost.
        if visited[pos]>0:
          continue

        visited[pos]=cost  
        # Also remember that we came from previous when we marked pos.
        # CHANGE 01_d: enter 'previous' (value) into the 'came_from' dictionary
        #   at index (key) 'pos'.
        came_from={pos:previous}

        # Check if the goal has been reached.
        print came_from
        if pos == goal:
            print came_from
            while pos:
                #print pos
                path.append(pos)
                pos = came_from[pos]         //here is the problem
            path.reverse()
            return (path, visited)
            break 

        # Check all neighbors.
        for dx, dy, deltacost in movements:
            # Determine new position and check bounds.
            new_x=pos[0]+dx
            new_y=pos[1]+dy
            if new_x<0 or new_x>=extents[0]:
              continue
            elif new_y<0 or new_y>=extents[1]:
              continue
            # Add to front if: not visited before and no obstacle.
            new_pos = (new_x, new_y)
            #   being the position 'we came from' (which is 'pos').
            if visited[new_pos]==0 and obstacles[new_pos]!=255: 
                heappush(front,(cost+deltacost,new_pos,pos))
    # CHANGE 01_d: Make sure to include the following code, which 'unwinds'
    #   the path from goal to start, using the came_from dictionary.
    #   Make sure to include the (modified!) return statement, otherwise
    #   the path will not show up in the visualization.

    # Reconstruct path, starting from goal.



# Main program.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Link functions to buttons.
    callbacks = {"update": update_callback,
                 "button_1_press": add_obstacle,
                 "button_1_drag": add_obstacle,
                 "button_1_release": update_callback,
                 "button_2_press": remove_obstacle,
                 "button_2_drag": remove_obstacle,
                 "button_2_release": update_callback,
                 "button_3_press": remove_obstacle,
                 "button_3_drag": remove_obstacle,
                 "button_3_release": update_callback,
                 }
    # Extra buttons.
    buttons = [("Clear", clear_obstacles)]

    # Init GUI.
    gui = gui.GUI(world_extents, 4, callbacks,
                  buttons, "on",
                  "Simple Dijkstra Algorithm (finally shows the optimal path "
                  "from start to goal).")

    # Start GUI main loop.
    gui.run()
```

Comment: I think the problem starts here: `came_from={pos:previous}`.  How would you describe what the intent of this line of code is?

Comment: For future reference, please copy and paste the stack trace of the error into the question, it's much easier to read there than in the screenshot.

Comment: I just use the new position as key (pos) to instore the old position.

Comment: Ok, it's not quite clear what you mean from that.  But here's what that line of code does instead of what you probably hoped: `came_from` is initialized to be an empty dictionary prior to `while front:`. And then it's entirely superseded here on this line: `came_from={pos:previous}`.  Any contents it had on any previous iteration are replaced with a new `dict` that has exactly one element.  You probably want instead `came_from[pos] = previous`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904086/the-key-error-in-dict#comment61371950_36904086), I discovered the solution. I should use `came_from[pos]=previous`.